# ListView header behaving in strange ways

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I've implemented a listview with a header using `addHeaderView()`.

The header is a simple XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/filter_wrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/filter_title"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Debates"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/filter"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />

</LinearLayout>
```

But, as you can see in this image

[image]

As I scroll down, the header goes up, and some times it flickers and goes down. Also, there is a bottom margin which is not reflected in the XML.

Any toughts?

Comment: what method have you used to `addHeaderView()` to the listview?

Comment: I think this due to emulator and if i'm not wrong then you are using Genymotion emulator so try to check in device.

Comment: It looks like you have added your header several times.

Comment: It is also happening in my device (Galaxy Note 2).

Answer (score 0):

I was calling `addHeaderView()` right after initializing the adapter.
Calling it before fixed the problem.